# how to access elements in javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays

how do I access the integers in the data object of this array?

Ultimately, I want to write a for loop to enter and compute the vpos (vertices).

```
var arrays = {
vpos : { numComponents: 3, data: 
                [
                    -.5,-1,-.5,  .5,-.5,-.5,  .5, .5,-.5,
                    -.5,-.5,-.5,  .5, .5,-.5, -.5, .5,-.5,
                    -.5,-.5, .5,  .5,-.5, .5,  .5, .5, .5
                ] },
    vnormal : {numComponents:3, data: [
                    0,0,-1, 0,0,-1, 0,0,-1,
                    0,0,-1, 0,0,-1, 0,0,-1,
                    0,0,1, 0,0,1, 0,0,1,
                    ]}
            };
```

Comment: What are you trying to compute the sum of the vpos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily calculate the total with [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```
let total = arrays.vpos.data.reduce((sum, val) => sum + val, 0);
```

Here is a demonstration:

```js
var arrays = {
  vpos: {
    numComponents: 3,
    data: [-.5, -1, -.5, .5, -.5, -.5, .5, .5, -.5, -.5, -.5, -.5, .5, .5, -.5, -.5, .5, -.5, -.5, -.5, .5, .5, -.5, .5, .5, .5, .5]
  }
};

let total = arrays.vpos.data.reduce((sum, val) => sum + val, 0);
console.log(total);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use [index] notation. Index is zero-based (first item has index of 0, 2nd one - 1, and so on).

```
arrays.vpos.data[0] //gives -0.5
arrays.vpos.data[1] //gives -1
arrays.vpos.data[2] //gives -0.5
```

Answer (score 0):

For `vpos`:

```
var pushedArray;
for(var x of arrays.vpos.data) {
    pushedArray.push(x);
}
```

`pushedArray` will have the values from the `data` array in it.

To add them:

```
var sum;
for(var x of pushedArray) {
    sum += x;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can get data array in d and then create for loop

```
var v =  {
vpos : { numComponents: 3, data: 
                [
                    -.5,-1,-.5,  .5,-.5,-.5,  .5, .5,-.5,
                    -.5,-.5,-.5,  .5, .5,-.5, -.5, .5,-.5,
                    -.5,-.5, .5,  .5,-.5, .5,  .5, .5, .5
                ] },
    vnormal : {numComponents:3, data: [
                    0,0,-1, 0,0,-1, 0,0,-1,
                    0,0,-1, 0,0,-1, 0,0,-1,
                    0,0,1, 0,0,1, 0,0,1,
                    ]}
            };
            var d = v.vpos.data;
            console.log(d);
```